# Is Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size) going to consider CPU cores, or should I do it. And is it worth it?

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency

In Android, is `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size)` going to consider CPU cores, or should I do it. And is it worth it?

If I want to load 50 images at once, I might be tempted to create a fixed thread pool with 50 threads, but:

- context switching
- number of available CPUs

might be factors that might make this even slower than maybe an executor using 2-3 threads, right?

So, is the `newFixedThreadPool` going to consider the CPU cores (and should it) or should I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Android, is Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size) going to consider CPU cores

No. You specify the number of threads. Android is not going to somehow scale that number of threads based upon CPU cores that the device has, let alone the number of CPU cores that are presently active.

> should I do it

Probably.

> And is it worth it?

Probably. In your case, you are heavily I/O bound, so having multiple threads is a good idea. However, 50 is likely to be too many (your cited context switching, plus just the heap space for 50 stacks). A typical sizing algorithm is (2 * number cores) + 1.